# Не работает цикл for с replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть код с подобным содержанием:

```
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_bab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_bar_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
```

И есть JQ:

```
for(i = 1000; i < 10; i++) {
  $('.asd').replace('ЗАМЕНИТЬ', i);
};
```

По логике в блоке `.asd` должно находиться слово **"ЗАМЕНИТЬ"** и меняться на число от **1000**, по **+1** в каждой следующей строке.

Но этот код не работает.
У меня дико подгорает.

Help me :с

Comment: таки ты применяешь `replace` сразу ко всем элементам... а не по очереди к каждому из них....... да и не понятно что ты в итоге желаешь получить с циклом от 1000 до 10...притом с инкементом `i` (что есть лишь одна итерация) и трёмя элементами `asd` О_о

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `$('.asd:nth-of-type(i)').replace(...);` - я правильно понял?

Comment: да... можно nth-of-type..... только `i` вынеси из строки, а то внутри кавычек она интерпрптируется просто как строка...., можно [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) ..... а еще цикл почини)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `asd` 193 штук, от **#define bla-bla-bla 1000** и до **#define bla-bla-bla 1193** .. Просто лень приписывать значения в ручную.. Врать не буду, в циклах я не силён, как именно починить?

Comment: "По логике ..." - откуда взялась такая "логика"?

Comment: @Igor, ну ладно, не по логике, а по задумке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` — функция *javascript*'а, и она применяется на строку.

Выборка *jquery* через селектор всегда возвращает **объект** *jquery*, а не строку. Соответственно, чтобы применять `replace` к строке, нужно после выбора элемента, брать его текст внутри через `text()`.

Также replace не поменяет текст сразу в исходном поле, он вернет лишь измененный. Поэтому, чтобы обратно записать в элемент измененный текст, нужно туда опять через `text()` вставить то, что ты заменяешь через `replace`

Ну и достать `i`-ый элемент можно либо с помощью **[nth-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)** либо **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** - на выбор.

```js
var start = 5;
var end = 10;

//var length = $('.asd').length;

for(i = start; i < end + 1; i++) { 
  var el = $( ".asd:nth-of-type(" + i +")" ); // var el = $('.asd').eq(i);  
  el.text(el.text().replace('ЗАМЕНИТЬ', i));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_bab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_bar_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
<div class="asd">#define spl_b_mab_m ЗАМЕНИТЬ</div>
```